# Idiomatic way of aggregating denormalized data

Tags: f#

I have a set of data of arrays of arrays. As an example

```
[[1,3],
 [4,3],
 [1,2],
 [7,2]]
```

I'd like to transform this to

```
[(3,[1,4])
 (2,[1,7])]
```

that is: create an array of tuples, where the first member is from index 1 of the original and the array is all the values of index 0 from the original grouped based on index 1. I can solve this imperatively but would like to do it in a more FP kind of way

Comment: I think you want to replace the commas in the first example with `;` and also to change `[]` to `[||]`

Comment: @JohnPalmer thanks but they are in no particular language :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

F# is a statically typed functional programming language so the first thing you want to do is convert your input into a typeful representation such as a list of pairs of ints:

```
[ 1, 3
  4, 3
  1, 2
  7, 2 ]
```

Then you can pipe it through the `Seq.groupBy` function using the `snd` function to key on the second element of each pair:

```
|> Seq.groupBy snd
```

This gives you `[3, [1, 3; 4, 3]; ...]` etc. so you want to map over the right hand sides extracting just the values (i.e. stripping out the keys) using the `fst` function:

```
|> Seq.map (fun (k, kvs) -> k, Seq.map fst kvs)
```

This gives your desired answer: `[(3, [1; 4]); (2, [1; 7])]`.

Comment: Though not the first to suggest this approach you were the first to actually describe the approach and for that I find it the better answer

Answer (score 5):

Use `Seq.groupBy` in combination with a few maps will get the desired result

```
[[1;3];
 [4;3];
 [1;2];
 [7;2]] 
|> Seq.groupBy (fun (a::b) -> b) 
|> Seq.map (fun (a,b) -> a,b|> Seq.toList) 
|> Seq.map (fun (a,b) -> a,b|>List.map (fun (c::d) -> c ))
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @John's answer, but assume that inner collections are arrays with at least two elements:

```
[|[|1; 3|];
  [|4; 3|];
  [|1; 2|];
  [|7; 2|]|]
|> Seq.map (fun arr -> arr.[0], arr.[1])
|> Seq.groupBy snd
|> Seq.map (fun (k, v) -> k, Seq.map fst v)

// val it : seq<int * seq<int>> = seq [(3, seq [1; 4]); (2, seq [1; 7])]
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer is not essentially different to the answers above, but it uses a bit of combinatory logic, so it looks more idiomatic (to me). Also, it has some validity check.

`Apply2` is essentially an [S combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic#Completeness_of_the_S-K_basis).

```
let data = 
    [[1;3];
     [4;3];
     [1;2];
     [7;2]]

// Apply2 operator applies two functions to x
// and returns both results as a tuple
let (.&.) f g x = f x, g x

// A naive validator for sequences
let assert' predicate message xs =
    if not <| Seq.forall predicate xs then
        failwith message
    xs

let aggregate data =
    data
    // validate the input
    |> assert' (List.length >> (=) 2) "All elements must be of length of two"
    // essentially, convert a 2-element list to a tuple
    |> Seq.map (List.head .&. (List.tail >> List.head))
    // group over the second element of a tuple
    |> Seq.groupBy snd
    // we no longer need the key element in a tuple, so remove it
    |> Seq.map (fst .&. (snd >> Seq.map fst))

aggregate data |> printf "%A"
```